# pulseaudio: no microphone configuration

Tags: 12.04, pulseaudio, microphone

Updated Ubuntu to precise from oneiric on a Dell Inspirion Mini 10 (with an Intel HDA-Soundcard). I can't remember having any issues with the microphone. I didn't need it - I tried ekiga the first time in precise.
I couldn't hear any sound in the echo test of ekiga, so I switched to the "System Preferences" and looked for the microphone to boost it. Surprisingly, the microphone input was greyed out - I couldn't mute or unmute, i couldn't even move the volume-slider.

On the other hand: I could change the microphone-setting on console with alsamixer, so don't worry about that… :)

I just wanted to ask, how to get pulseaudio back to the known, comfortable behaviour. Some newbies won't know the trick to use alsamixer…

My soundcard (output of lspci):

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)

Greets!

Answer (score 2):

Open the terminal using Ctrl+Alt+T or search for it in the dash.

Then type the command:

```
     killall pulseaudio
```

and press enter.